# Threaded prime generation in C, how can I give each thread its own start and end?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, primes

I am trying to write a program that generates prime numbers within a certain range and divide the work over a certain number of threads (start, end, and number of threads given as command line arguments). Each thread should produce ((end - start) / numThreads) primes, in order. So, if I want the program to produce the first 50 primes with 2 threads, thread 1 should produce 2-23 and thread 2 should produce 29-47. So far I have a main that deals with the command line args and does some error checking, and a function to create my threads. The issue I am having is that I am not sure how to give each thread it's own start and end. As far as I know, the start_routine can only take one argument. Is there a way to pass the thread function more than one argument? Or should I be thinking about this differently? Using POSIX threads. Thanks,
-DRB

Comment: I don't know what threading library you are using, but if you can only pass one parameter, can't you pass a pointer to a struct with as many fields as you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using POSIX threading:

Parse start/end in a structure, pass the structure instance with desired value as void* pointers while spawning threads.

```
    typdef struct boundary_s {
        int max;
        int min;
    } boundary_t;

    ...

    int main(...) {
        ...

        boundary_t thread_arg;
        thread_arg.max = INT_MAX;
        thread_arg.min = INT_MIN;

        pthread_create(<your thread handle>, <your thread attribute>, <your thread routine>, (void *) &thread_arg);

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Note: If you use the struct from stack, be sure to don't let it go out of scope in the lifetime of the thread. Or use malloc.

Answer (score 2):

Your one argument is a `void *`. Just make it a pointer to a structure, put whatever you want in there.

Eg,

```
struct Range {
  int begin;
  int end;
};
```

---

Note that your threads can't know how many primes they're going to generate, unless you already know all the primes. You can tell them the *input* range, and have them find all the primes in that range, though. Even then, they'll duplicate lots of work, because whichever thread has the higher range doesn't know all the primes before that.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a thread the argument can be anything, I send an array of pointers, each pointer pointing to one of the X arguments I want to send

like:

```
void* arguments[5];
arguments[0] = &integer;
arguments[2] = &string;
arguments[3] = &otherArray;
...etc...
```

and

```
createThread(thread, arguments);
```

then into the thread:

```
void* thread(void* arguments){
   void* args[] = (void*[])arguments;
   int* integer = arguments[0];
   string* string = arguments[1];
   ...etc...
}
```

Comment: OK that makes sense, would that be more efficient than passing a struct?

Comment: I don't think it will make any difference, the only difference is that the struct will have everyone defined with a name while a void* pointer will have variable arguments number and types without a name